# Extending scope of local variables in C over function calls

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

I have a library which provides function calls to a user as below:

```c
int* g_ID = NULL;

void processing(int p1, char p2)
{
  int ID = newID();

  g_ID = &ID;

  callback(p1, p2);

  return ID;
}

void SendResponse()
{
  sendID(*g_ID);
}
```

The user sets up its application by registering its callback function with the signature  `void (f*)(int p1, char p2)` and should not have knowledge about the ID used internally the library. So the user space code looks something like:

```c
main()
{
  RegisterCallback(HandleRequest);

  while (inProgress())
    sleep(1); /* just sleep here */
}

void (HandleRequest*)(int val1, char val2)
{
  /* ... do something user specific ... */

  SendResponse();

  return;
}
```

The problem here is, that the library (handling IDs and `g_ID` is not thread safe) !! User's callback is invoked asynchronously by other library functions, as threads. Several threads can be executed this way in parallel. But I won't give the user visibility of library internal IDs.

I know the code snippets above are not perfect. There're just to demonstrate my intention ... `SendResponse()` is not yet implemented ;-).

I hope, someone can give some ideas how to "implement" `SendResponse()` and to keep thread safety.

Comment: The only way to increase the lifetime of a local variable is to make it `static`. However that has the drawback that then all calls of the function will have the exact same variable, it will not be "local" per function call.

Comment: Well, first off, using a pointer to a local variable is bad - it'll most certainly get overwritten shortly after the call returns. You should instead use `malloc` or equivalent, or the `static` keyword like @Joachim suggested.

As for thread safety, if you're able to use C11 you can use the new `thread_local` keyword.

Comment: What I forgot to mention, is, that dynamic memory allocation is not allowed :-/ Everything must be "allocated" at compile time.

Comment: `static thread_local` should work (again, assuming you can use C11).

Comment: Well, unfortunately, `thread_local` is not available, since i'm using gcc 4.6 and C11 is first officially available with gcc 4.8.1 (what I got from other threads; even not sure if C11 is official so far, only C++11 seems to be).

Comment: Also, I'm cross-developing for different platforms, using cross-gcc-compilers with even smaller gcc versions (e.g. 4.4) ...

Comment: Thanks guys, it seems, as if I have to wait until all my gcc versions gets updated with official C11 support.

Comment: Can you use GCC's `__thread` instead of `thread_local`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a threadlocal here to keep the g_ID, rather than making using a global. This will work in the scenario, as I understand it, that there may be multiple concurrent calls to `process()` from different threads, but that the `process()` method is as shown - that the `SendResponse()` call will only occur within the scope (runtime scope, not lexical) of the `callback()` method.  That is true in the code shown. It could be untrue if HandleRequest did something exotic like kick off another thread an then return (but you could certainly ban that by documentation).

The other, more classic, approach is to encapsulate all the state you care about, like g_ID, into a `void *`, or `opaque_state *` or whatever, that you pass to the callback, and then methods like `SendRespose()` take that as an argument.  If you don't like `void *` you can implement the `opaque_state *` version without exposing any details of that structure using a forward declaration.

Comment: I didn't get your intention in the 1st paragraph ... could you give some small example please ?  For the 2nd: the point is, that all the user callbacks have one common signature and are already set up. Adding some variables, would mean, changing ALL user functions, which I wanted to avoid, but I might think of in future ...

Comment: Basically update the declaration of process() to be something like:

__threadlocal int* g_ID = NULL;

Then each assignment of g_ID inside the `process()` call will be independent of any other call to process (since g_ID is no longer global, but thread local).  All that will work if I understand well your requirements. Can you clearly identify the code that is the library code? The first sample? Who calls `process()`? Where is `callback()` defined?

Comment: The 1st piece of code is the library part, `processing()` is the thread function invoked b IPC message reception and `SendResponse()` shall be used by the user out of its function callback, here `HandleRequest`. The 2nd part is thus the user code. What is `__threadlocal`? And how does `SendResponse()` know `g_ID` if I make it local to `processing()`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `__thread` - see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.1/gcc/Thread-Local.html) for example (other platforms have the equivalent). You don't make g_ID local to processing. You keep it as a static, as before, but declare it with __thread, which means that each thread has a private value, so every callback() and methods called from there essentially sees its own version of g_ID. This will make more sense if you look up how thread local variables work.

Comment: Ok, I'll give `__thread` a try as soon as will have access again to all my platform development IDEs. I didn't know `__thread`, but it sounds quite promising. Thanks.